# 2D Per pixel collision detection not working

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I would like to say sorry in advance for the amount of code I will post, but I can't seem to get my collision detection to work, the player and the objects pass through each other with no effect when I play test.

I receive 0 warnings or errors, but the Player playerBot object does not seem to interact with any of the level items I have imported from GLEED2D.

One thing I did was to store the values of my item's rectangles and color arrays in lists so they could be all easily iterated through, maybe this is the source of the problem.

If you can spot why my code is not working I will be hugely grateful. I have removed any code that is definitely not relevant, and I am running VS 2010 with GLEED2D 1.3 if that helps.

Thanks again.

```
// Item Class ImageItem Downcast
public class ImageItem : Item
{
    public Texture2D Texture;
}

// Level
Level level;

// Ints
int iNumOfItems = 0;
int iTextureDataListNum = 0;
int iRectangleListNum = 0;

// Lists
List<Color []> itemTextureDataList = new List<Color[]>();
List<Rectangle> itemRectangleList = new List<Rectangle>();

protected override void Initialize()
{
    if (filename.Length > 0) level = Level.FromFile(filename, Content);
    else level = Level.FromFile("level1.xml", Content);

    foreach (Layer layer in level.Layers)
    {
        foreach (Item item in layer.Items)
        {
            iNumOfItems =+ 1;
        }
    }

    // Creates Player Ship
    playerBot = new Player(new Vector2(400f, 240f), new Vector2(0f, 0f));

    base.Initialize();
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    Texture2D pixel = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
    pixel.SetData(new[] { Color.White });
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    // Player Bot
    playerBot.LoadContent(Content, "Images/Player Bot Sprite Sheet", 40, 40, 4);

    // Assigns level textures color data to array
    foreach (Layer layer in level.Layers)
    {
        foreach (Item item in layer.Items)
        {
            ImageItem imageItem = item as ImageItem;
            if (imageItem != null)
            {
                Texture2D texture = imageItem.Texture;

                itemTextureDataList[iTextureDataListNum] = new Color[imageItem.Texture.Width * imageItem.Texture.Height];
                imageItem.Texture.GetData(itemTextureDataList[iTextureDataListNum]);
                iTextureDataListNum++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Creates a rectangle for every level texture
    foreach (Layer layer in level.Layers)
    {
        foreach (Item item in layer.Items)
        {   
            ImageItem imageItem = item as ImageItem;
            if (imageItem != null)
            {
                itemRectangleList[iRectangleListNum] = new Rectangle((int)imageItem.Position.X, (int)imageItem.Position.Y, imageItem.Texture.Width, imageItem.Texture.Height);
                iRectangleListNum++;
            }
        }
    }

    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Player Update
    playerBot.Update(gameTime);
    ((Sprite)playerBot).Update(gameTime);

    // Check for player collisons with level
    for (int i = 0; i < iNumOfItems - 1; i++)
    {
        if (IntersectPixels(playerBot.colRectangle, playerBot.textureDataArray, itemRectangleList[i], itemTextureDataList[i]) == true)
        {
            playerBot.StopMovement();
        }
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}

// Level Collision Detection Method

static bool IntersectPixels(Rectangle rectangleA, Color[] dataA, Rectangle rectangleB, Color[] dataB)
{
    // Find the bounds of the rectangle intersection
    int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
    int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
    int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
    int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);

    // Check every point within the intersection bounds
    for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
    {
        for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
        {
            // Get the color of both pixels at this point
            Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) + (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
            Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) + (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];

            // If both pixels are not completely transparent
            if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
            {
                // Then an intersection has been found
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // No intersection fond
    return false;
}
```

// Sprite Class

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    textureDataArray = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
    texture.GetData(textureDataArray);
```

// Player Class

```
public void StopMovement()
{
    velocity.X *= -1;
    velocity.Y *= -1;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste your questions from Gamedev (and don't do that; flag for migration there if it belongs here), at least avoid copying your downvote.

Comment: Draw the bounding rectangles as well, without reading your code, the number one mistake I used to make was not moving the bounding rectangle with the object, **Edit** just overlooked your code and you dont even use BoundingRectangle... why not?

Comment: Wooble, sorry for the bad etiquette, but no one on game dev helped me with my question, and i've been stuck on this problem for days. I can assure you I won't do it again.

Saysa, I created my own Rectangle using the texture height/width and adding in the correct origin Math. Although I doubt I did this optimally, how do you suggest implementing this BoundingRectangle? Thanks for the help guys, I have been pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: How are you not getting `index out of array bounds` exceptions? You should be getting those with the lines where you get Color data from the arrays...

Comment: I count the amount of item's in the level using a for each loop and sort it as the int iNumOfItems. I subtract 1 from that number to stop the for loop going out of bounds. Do you think this may be causing a problem? Like I said I have no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'll say here is, you should aim to be more Object Oriented in your approach.  Storing a list of textures and a list of rectangles alongside your list of Items is "bad" technique and going to eventually cause you some massive headaches when it comes to debugging.

So first of all, instead of having a list of Color[] and a list of Rectangle, add one Color[] and one Rectangle to your ImageItem class and work with those instead, or at least create a little class called "CollisionData" that has a Rectangle and a Color[] and store those in a single list.

Secondly, note that there is a Rectangle.Intersect(Rectangle A, Rectangle B) that gets your the rectangle of intersection.  So you can tidy up your code a bit by using that.

Your color checking can be simplified to (ColorA.A * ColorB.A != 0) as either being zero will 
cause the result to be zero.

Regarding not getting any errors, put a breakpoint at the start of the collision checking loop.  Does the application break?  If yes, what is the value of iNumItems? (you can hover over it to see the current value at point of breaking).  If no, then that section of code isn't being reached.  Put another breakpoint a bit further back and a bit further back until it gets hit, then figure out why the code isn't executing.

Comment: Thank you so much Steve, this is the kind of advice I was looking for and it is greatly appreciated. This coding business is tricky but highly rewarding I find, thanks for the help!

Comment: Turns out the imageitem = null, and therefore never added the texture data to the lists. I have made the changes you suggested, and my code is looking more streamlined, but I do not know how to make my imageItem not equal null.

Comment: It must be that your items in your list are not of class (and are not derived from) ImageItem so "ImageItem imageItem = item as ImageItem;" is setting to NULL instead of casting as you would hope.

Comment: Thanks Steve, although I already got around this by instead of downcasting to a new class, I simply added the ImageItem members to the original class.